# Mocking Postman GET request using axios is giving different results

Tags: reactjs, request, axios, postman

I am trying to mock up the following request , which I have in Postman, into Axios:

in terms of **cURL**:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://url' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer blablabla' \
--data-raw '{
    "category":{
        "value": "category1"
    }
}'
```

in terms of **Nodejs-Request**:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'http://url',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer blablabla'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"category":{"value":"category1"}})

};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

*Note: the first two codes had been generated by Postman.*

When I send this request via Postman, and dump the request parametes on the server, I will get the following result:

```
array:1 [
  "category" => array:1 [
    "value" => "category1"
  ]
]
```

in terms of **Axios**:

```
var config = {
    params: {
        category:
        {
            value: 'category1'
        }
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer blablabla'
    }
};

return Axios.get('http://url', config);
```

While dumping the parameters sent via Axios will generate the following result:

```
array:1 [
  "category" => "{"value":"category1"}"
]
```

Note the difference between the two results, where the value of the category in the first result is an **array**, but its a **string** in the second !!

How I can fix my Axios request to get the same result as same as the Postman request?

Comment: hey! did you got it working? I am facing a similar issue